# Volume doesn't work in a docker container and forgets data

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I'm trying to build Django + Docker + PostgreSQL

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10.0-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apk update
RUN apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn pets.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - .env
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - web
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $POSTGRES_HOST $POSTGRES_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

cd pets
python manage.py flush --no-input
python manage.py migrate

exec "$@"
```

So, when the container starts i use `docker exec -it <container_id> python manage.py createsuperuser` to create a superuser and then add some data to database.

But, when i use docker-compose stop and then running again with the same id the container forgets about the written data and everything has to be repeated.

Shouldn't volume solve this issue?

Comment: You run `python manage.py flush` in your entrypoint (?) which removes all data from the database https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#flush

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks a lot! if you want, you can post it as an answer, i will accept